# What are the best practices for AWS EC2 instance naming conventions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS.

What are the best practices for naming instances/volumes for EC2. At the moment our instance(s) will be in one location, and availability zone. We are running Windows 2012.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amazon EC2 instance naming is done by using Tags (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html)

We do not provide best practices for naming, it really depends on your application, project, organisation.

Some customers are using tags per

- environments (dev, tes, prod)
- org unit (marketing, hr, tax...)
- project / app name
- expiration date (for temporary resources)
- cost center code
- ...

You can combine all these, up to 10 tags per resources

Seb

Answer (score -1):

There are none. You can name and tag instances in ways that work best for you. Some automation tools may add their own tags.